# How to crawl asynchronized content by Java?

Tags: java, ajax, web-crawler

I need to crawl a site by Java while a section of content of it is loaded by ajax. Does anyone have experience how to get those content?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You can use [HtmlUnit](http://htmlunit.sourceforge.net/). It is a headless browser.

For example, with html unit you can press button on the page, wait for content get loaded by ajax and grab it.